# Placing multiple raphael.js objects on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, raphael

I am new to raphael.js and want to use it to make small pie charts that show the progress percentage. I have prepared the function to plot the chart and it works well if I have only one chart on the page. However, when I add additional  elements, the charts overlap. I iterate through the `.min-pie-chart` elements:

```
$(".min-pie-chart").each(function () {
  var value = $(this).data("percent");
  Raphael($(this), 20, 20).minPieChart(10, 10, 8, value, "rgb(89,185,86)", "rgb(75,175,72)");
});
```

I'm guessing this is a css issue which is new to me as well.

A demonstration is located [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cannibalflea/7k3zbfhq/).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust its location based on some factor. In this case, maybe it makes sense to adjust an offset according to its index in the list.

You can get an index from the anonymous function...

```
each(function (index) {
```

then

```
minPieChart(30, (index + 1) * 20, 8, value,
```

as an example. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7k3zbfhq/8/)

Comment: Is there no way to have the objects appear in line with the text like an image? This solution means that the location would have to be predetermined and would not readjust on resize, for example.

Comment: The best that I could come up with was using background-image property of the <div> and injecting svg into it as shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cannibalflea/zvybwkjp/6/)

Comment: Or you just add a text element alongside the image.